Crash with ForegroundServiceDidNotStartInTimeException on Android 14
I have foreground service with notification that tracks user location, but in the Crashlytics I see that the app crashes for some users with Android 14. I can not reproduce it.
 Fatal Exception: android.app.RemoteServiceException$ForegroundServiceDidNotStartInTimeException: Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground(): ServiceRecord{2170719 u0 com.anstar.fieldworkhq/.coordinates.ServiceTechnicianTrackingService}
   at android.app.ActivityThread.generateForegroundServiceDidNotStartInTimeException(ActivityThread.java:2315)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.throwRemoteServiceException(ActivityThread.java:2286)
Caused by android.app.StackTrace: Last startServiceCommon() call for this service was made here
   at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:2023)
   at android.app.ContextImpl.startForegroundService(ContextImpl.java:1967)
   at android.content.ContextWrapper.startForegroundService(ContextWrapper.java:847)
   at android.content.ContextWrapper.startForegroundService(ContextWrapper.java:847)
   at com.zoran.app.main.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticApiModelOutline0.m(D8$$SyntheticClass)
   at com.zoran.app.main.MainActivity.startForegroundService(MainActivity.java:326)
   at com.zoran.app.main.MainActivity.tryToStartForegroundLocationService(MainActivity.java:313)
   at com.zoran.app.main.MainActivity.trackLocationIfNeeded(MainActivity.java:220)
   at com.zoran.app.main.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:95)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8975)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8944)

As you can see the crash happens in the MainActivity, when I tried to star foreground service with this code:
private void trackLocationIfNeeded() {
if (presenter.isTrackable()) {
  if (ViewUtil.isPlayServiceAvailable(this)) {
    if (isForegroundLocationPermissionGranted() && presenter.isTrackTechnicianRouteAllowed()) {
      tryToStartForegroundLocationService();
      presenter.saveThatUserAskedForPermission();
    } else {
      if (!presenter.isUserAskedForLocationPermission()) {
        askForLocationPermission();
        presenter.saveThatUserAskedForPermission();
      }
    }
  }
} else {
  stopServiceTechnicianLocationService();
}
} 

private void tryToStartForegroundLocationService() {
if(Utils.isPlayServiceAvailable(this)) {
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
    if(isPostNotificationsPermissionGranted()) {
      startForegroundService();
    } else {
      askForPostNotificationsPermission();
    }
  } else {
    startForegroundService();
  }
}
}

private void startForegroundService() {
Intent i = new Intent(this, ServiceTechnicianTrackingService.class);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
  startForegroundService(i);
} else {
  startService(i);
}
}

startForegroundService(i); is the line 326.
This is my foreground location tracking service with startCommand where I try at the beginning to start service with a notification.
public class ServiceTechnicianTrackingService extends Service {

private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
private LocationCallback locationCallback;

@Inject ServiceTechnicianLocationManager serviceTechnicianCoordinateManager;
@Inject NetworkManager NetworkManager;

public static final String ACTION_STOP_SERVICE = "action_stop_service";
private boolean isStarted = false;

@Nullable @Override public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
return null;
}

@Override public void onCreate() {
super.onCreate();
injector().inject(this);

fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
  @Override public void onLocationResult(@NotNull LocationResult locationResult) {
    if(locationResult != null && locationResult.getLastLocation() != null) {
      super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
      String lat = String.valueOf(locationResult.getLastLocation().getLatitude());
      String lng = String.valueOf(locationResult.getLastLocation().getLongitude());

      Timber.d("Lat is: " + lat + " lng is: " + lng);
      if(networkManager.isNetworkAvailable()) {
        serviceTechnicianCoordinateManager.updateCurrentLocation(new Coordinate(lat, lng));
      }
    }
  }
};
}
@Override public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
// Call startForeground early to prevent the exception
if(!isStarted) {
  startForegroundAndDisplayNotification();
  isStarted = true;
 }

if(intent != null) {
  String action = intent.getAction();
  if(ACTION_STOP_SERVICE.equalsIgnoreCase(action)) {
    stopForeground(true);
    stopSelf();
  } else {
    requestLocationUpdates();
  }
}
return START_STICKY;
}

@Override public void onDestroy() {
super.onDestroy();
stopLocationUpdates();
isStarted = false;
}

private void startForegroundAndDisplayNotification() {
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
  try {
    Notification notification = createNotification();
    startForeground(1, notification);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    Timber.e(e, "Exception in startForegroundAndDisplayNotification");
  }
}
}

In AndroidManifest file I have this:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />

<service
  android:name=".coordinates.ServiceTechnicianTrackingService"
  android:enabled="true"
  android:exported="false"
  android:foregroundServiceType="location" />


The ForegroundServiceDidNotStartInTimeException typically occurs when startForeground(...) is not called within five seconds of the service starting. From your description, it seems the onCreate() method in your service contains significant logic, which delays the onStartCommand() method where startForeground(...) is typically called. This delay can indeed lead to the ForegroundServiceDidNotStartInTimeException.
To mitigate this, I recommend initiating startForegroundAndDisplayNotification() at the beginning of the onCreate() method. This ensures the service is promoted to a foreground service as quickly as possible, which is crucial for compliance with Android's service lifecycle requirements, especially from API level 26 onwards.
Furthermore, your handling of different Android versions in the startForeground(...) method needs a slight adjustment for Android 10 (API level 29) and above, where specifying the foreground service type becomes mandatory if your app targets API level 29 or higher. Here's how you can adjust your implementation:
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) { // API level 26
    Notification notification = createNotification();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) { // API level 29
        startForeground(
            SERVICE_ID,
            notification,
            ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_LOCATION
        );
    } else {
        startForeground(SERVICE_ID, notification);
    }
}

For further details on handling foreground service types, you can refer to the official Android documentation: Foreground services.

Thanks, Fidan. Thanks for the explanation and code. So, I need to change my logic when starting the service to add a flag for a foreground service type. I guess without this flag it throws exceptions sometimes, right?
When you say onCreate() method, do you mean onCreate of the service or the activity from where the service is called?

Following up on this?

" I guess without this flag it throws exceptions sometimes, right?" -> Yes from android 14(SDK 34) it throw exception when you don't declared foregroundType for Foreground Service.

"When you say onCreate() method, do you mean onCreate of the service or the activity from where the service is called?" ->   I mean to the onCreate of Service of course!

I have added onCreate() and onStartCommand() of my service. Do you see anything that that could cause this issue?

Hi @Zookey,If you're referring to adding onCreate() and onStartCommand(), there is no issue with calling both methods in a Service, as they serve different purposes. However, if you are considering calling startForeground(..) in both functions, that is not the best practice. You should only call it in the way I mentioned in my response regarding onCreate(). Function

No, I mean that I have posted my question code from both onCreate() and onStartCommand(). Do you see if I am doing anything wrong in those 2 methods that that causes this exception?
